Which Postgres schema should I go with?
This is my first time working with databases. I'm designing a database for an e-commerce project. I ended up with two versions of the schema, and I don't know which one to go with or what its pros and cons are.
V1:
-- Person Schema
create table person
(
    id      serial primary key,
    name    text    not null,
    email   text    null,
    phone   text    not null,
    address text    null,
    balance integer not null default 0
);

-- Product Schema
create table product_category
(
    id        serial primary key,
    name      text not null,
    parent_id integer references product_category (id)
);

create table product_price
(
    id              serial primary key,
    suggested_price integer not null,
    wholesale_price integer not null,
    lowest_price    integer not null
);

create table product_stock
(
    id            serial primary key,
    current_stock integer not null,
    warning_stock integer not null
);

create table product
(
    id       serial primary key,
    name     text    not null,
    cost     integer not null,
    image    text    not null,

    category integer references product_category (id),
    price    integer references product_price (id) unique,
    stock    integer references product_stock (id) unique,
    supplier integer references person (id)
);

V2:
-- Person Schema
create table person
(
    id      serial primary key,
    name    text    not null,
    email   text    null,
    phone   text    not null,
    address text    null,
    balance integer not null default 0
);

-- Product Schema
create table product_category
(
    id         serial primary key,
    name       text not null,
    parent_id  integer references product_category (id),
    product_id integer references product (id)
);

create table product_price
(
    id              serial primary key,
    suggested_price integer not null,
    wholesale_price integer not null,
    lowest_price    integer not null,
    product_id      integer references product (id) unique
);

create table product_stock
(
    id            serial primary key,
    current_stock integer not null,
    warning_stock integer not null,
    product_id    integer references product (id) unique
);

create table product
(
    id       serial primary key,
    name     text    not null,
    cost     integer not null,
    image    text    not null,

    supplier integer references person (id)
);

The first schema relies on storing foreign keys inside the main table product while version 2 does not. Which version is better and why?

This might not put the ball in the basket, but here is a schema that I've used with a lot of success for stuff like this:

[transaction_type]s are: add; remove; and reconcile. You'll need a very simple procedure or table valued function to get a current state of inventory. Further, you'd be able to generate state of inventory at any particular date. The inventory table is a time machine!
Product history is probably the most expendable item in this list. If you don't really care about how the product attributes have changed over time, leave it out.

In V1, columns price and stock are each unique in the product table.
In V2, column product_id is unique in product_price and product_id is also unique in product_stock.
So, both schemas allow for only one product_price per product and only one product_stock per product.
Is that what you want?
If so, there seems to be no reason to have the product_price and product_stock tables. Why not just add the price and stock columns to the product table?
